# Adding custom filters to list pages

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I've created a custom brand new list page with all the required parts.  Now I've added a filter to the top similar to ProjProjectsListPage, in fact I have the same Active/All as that form (however with my own custom EDT instead).  The filter works perfect except that when I enter the form, the Active shows as the default selected option yet All records show instead.  When I select All and then back to Active, it does filter it as I expect.  It is my intent to have only Active records show by default.

I notice that ProjProjectsListPage defaults their value to All, opposite of what I'm trying to do.  But in trying to figure out what that example does, I look at the control's Selected property and notice it is set at its default value, I also don't see anything in the interaction class that changes it to All.  So, I'm a little confused on how that works that way.

But ultimately, I'm trying to do something similar, but not quite, I'm trying to have Active be the default value (which it is), but also have the query recognize this filter on form load (not working).  I've tried adding these few lines in initializeQuery() before the super():

```
NewActiveAllEDT activeAll;

customFilter = SysEPCustomFilter::construct(formStr(NewListPage));
customFilter.load();

customFilter.setInitialFilterControlValue(formControlStr(NewListPage, CtrlActiveAll), 0);

activeAll = customFilter.getFilterControlValue(formControlStr(NewListPage, CtrlActiveAll));
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(_query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(NewTable)), fieldNum(NewTable, Status)).value(SysQueryRangeUtil::customMethodToFilterThisStatus(activeAll));
```

...this made it filter correctly on form load, however, the Active/All filter then no longer functions, when I select All it appears to do nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found the solution already, but I was running into the same problem. I found out that there is a property called "Save filter" on the field group in your listpage. Change it from No to Yes, and your filter will work when opening the form.

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an if condition

```
if (this.listPage().listPageArgs().parameters())
{ 
     activeAll = customFilter.getFilterControlValue(formControlStr(NewListPage, CtrlActiveAll));
     SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(_query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(NewTable)), fieldNum(NewTable, Status)).value(SysQueryRangeUtil::customMethodToFilterThisStatus(activeAll));
}
```